# Check if record exists if it does add 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple Database I use for storing the Url, Title and number of downloads of a youtube video. I'm now using this basic query to insert the Title and Url:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO youtube (ID, Titel, Downloads, Url) VALUES (NULL, '".$title."', '1', '".$my_id."')";
$mysqli->query($query);
```

In the 'Downloads' column I am currently just inserting 1.
My question is how can I check if the url already exists in the DB and if it does I want to edit that record so it adds 1 to the 'Downloads'.

Comment: The question seems to answer itself -- you check if it exists and add one if it does exist.  How are you having problems doing so?

Comment: You should always list the columns explicitly in the `insert` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO youtube VALUES (NULL, 'title', '1', 'id')
ON DUPLICATE KEY update Downloads = Downloads +1
```

Note that you should use prepared statements for all database interactions.

Here is the code using my safemysql lib for example

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO youtube VALUES (NULL, ?s, 1, ?s)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY update Downloads = Downloads + 1";
$db->query($sql, $title, $my_id);
```

Comment: This looks like it should work but it is still just inserting a new record every time I download a video. Any idea what can cause this?

Comment: yes sure. you have to have a UNIQUE index on that field that you want to check for duplicates. it works this way

Comment: Still can't get it to work somehow, I am probably just doing 1 stupid thing which messes it up every time. I have the ID on Auto increment and it has a unique index. It will still insert a new record then.

Comment: @Daanvn - are you using UPPER to make sure you are always checking without upper lower case issues?

Comment: yes, sure you are right about this thing. By inserting NULL for id you will never make it duplicate. And I doubt it's id you want to check for dupes

Comment: @Hogan would you please delete your irrelevant comment?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I removed the ID and set the Url to UNIQUE and it works now, Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL offers the ON DUPLICATE clause on inserts:

```
INSERT INTO youtube VALUES (NULL, '".$title."', '1', '".$my_id."')"
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE downloads = downloads + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
INSERT INTO youtube (Titel, Downloads, Url) VALUES ('$title', '1', '$url')
ON DUPLICATE KEY update Downloads = Downloads + 1
```

But you must define the `url` column as `UINQUE` or as `PRIMARY KEY`.

You could use:

```
ALTER TABLE youtube
ADD UNIQUE (Url)
```